# Why isn't gold used as a currency in Krynn?

Tags: dragonlance, money

For some reason in Krynn steel is valued greater than gold. This seems odd since steel is more common (and more practical), whereas gold is rare. Steel has the disadvantage of being susceptible to corression and easier to find. What caused the people to turn away from gold as a reliable monetary standard?

Comment: FWIW, the concept of 'gold' as a currency is under copyright (not sure who holds it), which is why most games use something other than gold as currency (gil, rupees, etc)

Comment: Maybe gold is a more common metal in Krynn than it is in Earth.

Comment: @Jeff: "The concept of gold as a currency" is not copyrightable. Concepts are not copyrightable, only fixed forms.

Comment: @SeanMcMillan: I phrased it poorly - the use of the term 'gold' to represent in-game currency is what I'd heard was under copyright.  I cannot find a reference online though, so it may have been incorrect information.

Comment: @Jeff Given that gold has been used as currency and trade goods in the real word since time immemorial, I suspect that even Disney's lawyers would have let the copyright lapse by now.

Comment: One does not simply 'find' steel.

Comment: @Mazura I found some in my yard, it is shaped like an oil barrel (buried).

Comment: Pedant, coming through: The answer states why they use steel, but not why they *don't* use gold. For that, we have to look at why *we* do: "The problem is [that other metals] are very hard to smelt. You need to get your furnace up into the region of 1,000C before you can begin to extract these metals from their ores. That kind of specialist equipment wasn't available to ancient man." (–[BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-25255957)) and of course, *ooh shiny!* Apparently, Krynn has its priorities more in order then we do.

Comment: The standard answer among D&D fans for many years is that Weiss and Hickman are hacks, as writers: that's why.  (But if true, very successful hacks! :) I certainly enjoyed reading their stories).   But I doubt that answer would be helpful to you.

Comment: Are different steel alloys valued differently? After all, steel itself is an alloy of iron and other minerals.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to a few sites containing documentation on the Dragonlance RPG, so set in the same world as the books, the reason for steel is because its relative usefulness has restricted the supply of it.  You value your weapons and armour a lot more when you know it's worth its weight in... err... steel.

> The world of Krynn, however, uses steel as the base currency, with gold down near the bottom in value. The reason for this is tied up in the history of the world, when steel became very rare after most of the alloy was used to make arms and armor.

[Source](http://www.helium.com/items/1326607-dungeons-and-dragons-economy)

Given the frequent invasions and wars, having an intrinsically valuable currency can make sense because if all else fails, you can always stab someone with it.

Comment: As a convenient byproduct, this allows GMs to insert vast piles of gold into dragon lairs without having to worry too much about the players becoming absurdly wealthy when they claim it, as gold coins aren't any more valuable than copper ones.

Answer (score 3):

#### After the Cataclysm, steel's value increased exponentially for practical reasons.

During the [Age of Might](https://dragonlance.fandom.com/wiki/Age_of_Might), silver and gold were the common metals that denoted richness: I (vaguely) remember the description, in the [Legend of the Twins trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonlance_Legends), of the city of Istar and of its inhabitants, whom general level of wealth was very high. In this [webpage](https://dragonlance.fandom.com/wiki/Istar) one can read

> Istar was a huge city, built almost entirely of crystal, alabaster, and gold.

and the other references in that webpage point to other official products (novels, adventures) that confirm this.

In the most recent official Dragonlance product [*Shadow of the Dragon Queen*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sotdq) one can read, at page 10, under the **Currency** section the reason why steel (and bronze) coins have been used so far:

> Since the Cataclysm, the harsh realities of daily survival leave little room for impracticality. For years after the devastation, steel's value skyrocketed until it was valued as high as gold, thanks to the difficulty of forging steel and its obvious practical applications. Similarly, bronze was valued on par with silver. While the value of steel and bronze has diminished to pre-Cataclysm standards, trade coins of bronze and steel remain in use across Ansalon.

Comment: *What caused the people to turn away from gold as a reliable monetary standard?* - a giant rock, +1.

Answer (score 2):

I assume it's because it's easier to make weapons and armor with your money when you need to. So wealth = liquid military power. You won't invade a country with 10,000 steel because they can use that steel to make arms and armor easily.

Comment: That would bring new meaning to *no quarter*.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons for this:

1. Steel has practical value. It can be used to make weapons and armor, which are essential to survival after the Cataclysm.
2. Because of the Cataclysm, many veins of gold that were previously inaccessible became easy to mine.  Because gold became more commonplace, its value dropped.

However, if good steel is now currency, it can't be used for armor and weapons.  We always assumed there were 2 grades of steel: "noble" ore and "common."  The "common" ore is filled with impurities, and has the same capabilities as bronze,  Whereas "Noble" ore is true, good steel enjoyed by every other game world.  However, it is too valuable to be used as weapons and armor.  A weapon made of noble ore would cost its weight in steel.  So, a longsword made of this should cost 200 Stl.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve your answer if you cite sources for some of your assertions, like the after-effects of the Cataclysm and the noble/common steel division.